# use stl map as member of struct

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm constructing a struct with one of the member being a map.
First question is this allowed? The compiler did not complain.

```
struct A {  
  map<int, float> B;  
}
```

Later I declare an array of such data type.

```
A *C = (A *)INTERNAL_CALLOC(..., sizeof(A));
```

Here the function `INTERNAL_CALLOC` is a functional wrapper of MALLOC.
Later on in the code when I try to first time insert an item into the array's first element's map, I got a core dump.

```
C[0].B[0] = 0.001;
```

Any idea why is this the case?
Thanks!

Comment: the code part did not come out right. the line after the struct A is "map <int,float> B;"

Comment: You should not be using `malloc` to allocate C++ objects (which your struct is).  You should use `new`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a map in a struct is fine.

Allocating with `malloc` is definitely **not** fine; the constructor is not called.  So your map will most likely do something terrible when you attempt to use it.

General rule of thumb: don't use `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`/`free` in C++.  Avoid dynamic allocation wherever possible, and use `new`/`delete` when unavoidable.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* And read up on *smart pointers*.</sub>

Comment: What should I do to make sure the constructor is called? Thanks.

Comment: Will give new/delete a try. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you really must allocate with INTERNAL_CALLOC, then use placement new.

First, you must define a constructor and a destructor for the type A, or define A as a class:

```
struct A {
  A(){}
  ~A(){}
  map<int, float> B;  
};
```

Then you can simply call:

```
//Allocate an A, uninitialized
A *C = (A *)INTERNAL_CALLOC(..., sizeof(A));  
//Initialize the newly allocated A
new (C) A();
```

later when you free the object you must explicitly call the destructor:

```
//A *C;
C->~A();
INTERNAL_free(C);
```

Comment: Tried this method, but got the same error. For now I'm switching to using new to allocate the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
A *C = (A *)INTERNAL_CALLOC(..., sizeof(A));
```

Here you are lying to the compiler. You are telling it that the return value from `INTERNAL_CALLOC` points to an `A`, but it doesn't, it just points to zeroes. Use `new`.

Comment: Your word is strong, but I like you explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Allocating memory using malloc does not initialize the array elements.

Comment: It doesn't initialize the map *at all*, has nothing to do with elements.

Comment: @Ed The array elements are of class A. The map is a member of class A, so if the array elements are not initialized (like I said), the maps are not initialized either (like you said). If the array elements were initialized (like when operator new[] where used), the map would have been initialized as well (because that's how C++ works). So it has exactly to do with the array elements not being initialized, and nothing else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you meant map when you said array.  My mistake, I shouldn't have assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a valid `std::map<whatever...>` by filling memory with zero bytes.

To a certain extent, it's possible with POD types (approximately, "pure C" data structures).

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `std::map` as a member, 
I recommend to use `std::vector` instead of plain array to be the container.

You can do as follow:

```
struct A
{
    std::map<int, int> B;
};

std::vector<A> vecofmap;    

A elem0;
A elem1;
A elem2;

vecofmap.push_back(elem0);
vecofmap.push_back(elem1);
vecofmap.push_back(elem2);

vecofmap[0].B[0] = 100;

std::cout << vecofmap[0].B[0] <<std::endl;
```

Then no needs to bother with memory allocation.